# Bika health Installation Error

Tags: plone

Am I've been trying to install bika health on windows 7 64bits without success. When I run buildout, I get the following error:

Error: Coundn't Install: Bika.Health 1.3.6.

Pls I need help.

Comment: please post full error and your buildout config

Answer (score 1):

You might have wanted version 3.1.6 ....

Comment: yes its trying to install version 3.1.6. Is that the problem? Should I force it to install 3.1.5?

Comment: you mentioned "1.3.6" is that a typo in your buildout, or here on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I have resolved the issue. I uninstalled and reinstalled plone but the problems continued. So I did the second uninstall and checked C:/ drive but plone43 folder was still there. I had to manually delete the it before reinstalling and ran buildout and it went successfully. So now, am up and running with Bika Health. Thanks again @Danimal and @vangheem for your 
concern.